# hasAttribute in lxml?

Tags: xpath, python-2.7, attributes, lxml

```
path4 = file.xpath('/p:sld/p:cSld/p:spTree/p:sp/p:nvSpPr/p:nvPr/p:ph[@type="body"][@sz="quarter"][@marL=True]', namespaces={'p':'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/presentationml/2006/main',
            'a':'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main'})
```

here is a path that I am using for a parsed xml file. I was using `x.hasAttribute('marL') == True:` using  `ElementTree` but i dont know how to use `hasAttribute` in `lxml` to check the whether `p:ph` contains an attribute called `marL`. I tried the above but dint work and also I didnt find it on lxml examples. Can any1 suggest what is the function in lxml  for `hasAttribute` or usage of it for the above instance?

Any help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The xpath predicate for  attribute exist would be simple be: `[@marL]`
Therefore try:

```
'/p:sld/p:cSld/p:spTree/p:sp/p:nvSpPr/p:nvPr/p:ph[@type="body"][@sz="quarter"][@marL]'
```

or:

```
'/p:sld/p:cSld/p:spTree/p:sp/p:nvSpPr/p:nvPr/p:ph[@type="body" and  @sz="quarter"  and  @marL]'
```

For more information to predicates look for example [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev).
*" `employee[@secretary and @assistant]` selects all the employee children of the context node that have both a secretary attribute and an assistant attribute"*

Comment: Thats perfect but how to check whether p:ph has attribute type, quarter and not marl i,e  x.hasAttribute('marL') == False. I need to use this condition to get different text out of a tag. I tried @marL=False which dint work!

Comment: Sorry I do not understand check "whether p:ph". Xaph like e.g :`'//p:ph[@type="body" and  @sz="quarter"  and  @marL]'` will return all p:ph which fulfill the "filter condition in the *predicate*.

Comment: thats right but i want to check whether `p:ph` tag has an attribut `@type='body'` and `@sz="quarter"` and also check whether it contains an attribute called `@marL`. If yes True or if p:ph does not have attribute marL then  false. I hope it is more convinving now!

Comment: to make it more simple this was line using ElementTree `if all10.nodeName == 'a:pPr' and all10.getAttribute('lvl') == '2' and all10.hasAttribute('marL') == False:` and i want to rewrite this in `lxml` thats it!!

Comment: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16912361/rewrite-elementtree-code-in-lxml` check this out for more detail..Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
path4 = file.xpath('boolean(/p:sld/p:cSld/p:spTree/p:sp/p:nvSpPr/p:nvPr/p:ph[@type="body"][@sz="quarter"]/@marL)', namespaces={'p':'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/presentationml/2006/main',
            'a':'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main'})
```