# rewrite ElementTree code in lxml

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, lxml, elementtree

I am writing a code to extract text from a xml file using ElementTree but I found out that    lxml is giving xpath features which is more convenient. So i want to know how this line could be rewritten in lxml

```
if x.nodeName == 'a:pPr' and x.getAttribute('lvl') == '2' and x.hasAttribute('marL') == False:
```

currently I am suggested to  use this..

```
'/p:sld/p:cSld/p:spTree/p:sp/p:nvSpPr/p:nvPr/x[@type="body" and  @sz="quarter"  and  @marL]'
```

Hope my question is clear!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are already at a stage where you're ready to use an xpath. If not http://lxml.de/parsing.html should help.
The xpath for finding the element, you are searching for in your first line should look like this:

```
"//a:pPr[@lvl=2 and not(@marL)]"
```

I however have to admit that I have no idea how your second snippet should find that element O_o

Comment: Thank you so much..I was trying this since yesterday..cheers :)

Comment: could you please tell me what should i use in lxml to replace 
`x.firstChild.nodeName == 'a:r'` since `getnext()` and `getprevious()` does not give the very next child but gives the next parent node itself..I hope my question is clear :)

Comment: you should be able to use this xpath: *[1][self::a:r]

Comment: i need a suggestion for this `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16938112/text-extraction-using-python-lxml-looping-issue` ...Thanks